# homepage performance related ajax + wordpress + table loading on home page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, performance, pagination

Have basic performance question--

i need to display an table of 7 columns that has say example million records (partial post info of custom post type fields )

my pagination logic shows only first 5 records on home page , upon click on pagination button it shows next 5 records and so on till end of records (i.e million records .)

since it is home page , i am not sure if having this table on landing page will affect the loading time ??

i am pulling the records via ajax method along with pagination logic , does it mean when an user visits my home page , millions of records are fetched first and then my home page will be loaded ??
or is it only first 5 records would be fetched and my home page will be displayed .

whats the best solution to deal with this situation , i need table at my home page for users to shows first 5 records under table